# Mouse Click event get name of the bar EXT JS

Tags: extjs, event-handling, mouselistener

I am new to EXT JS. I have a bar chart with items when click on the single

in the below image if we do mouse click on metric two i should get 27 value in mouse click event

[image]

Please help

Answer (score 2):

You need to add plugin in cartesian chart config

```
        plugins: {
           ptype: 'chartitemevents',
           moveEvents: true
        },
```

And Listener in the series config

```
        listeners: {
            itemclick: function (chart, item, event, eOpts) {
               console.log(item.record.get('pay'));
            }
        },
```

Please check the solution in the fiddle below
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3mua

Comment: i have tried with the same but getting a plugin issue.. I have added a plugin too but no luck

Comment: Can you share the fiddle over here.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `itemclick` listener to the `Ext.chart.CartesianChart`, see [documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/modern/Ext.chart.CartesianChart.html#event-itemclick). This will be called when an item (a bar) is clicked on the chart.

See this code:

```
xtype: 'cartesian',
axes: [...],
series: [...],
listeners: {
  itemclick: function(chart, item, event, eOpts) { 
    // here you can access the chart and the clicked item,
    // for example `item.record` will reference the data 
    // displayed etc.
    // (you can put a breakpoint here and evaluate the variables)
  }
}
```

Comment: listener needs to added in series config.

Comment: @DevendraHaldankar Both `Ext.chart.CartesianChart` and `Ext.chart.series.Bar` have `itemclick` listeners, and they work the same way, try with your fiddle. See documentation [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.chart.series.Bar.html#event-itemclick) and [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.chart.CartesianChart.html#event-itemclick).

Comment: @DevendraHaldankar You are right about the plugin, I forgot that.